# Multiple lists sorting

Tags: c#

I have 2 lists

```
List<ClassEmpInfo> employeeDetails = GetEmployeeDetails();  //returns list of values

And ClassEmpInfo class has  following attributes.

empID,
empName,
empAddress etc.
```

for ex:

```
200  John  Harmington Road.
500  Mark  Pearl Blvd.
```

second list

```
> List<EmpID> employeeSortOrder = GetEmpSortOrder();
> 
> ie. employeeSortOrder will have
> 
> Id/ranking
> 
 1 500
 2 200 
 3 300
 4 700
```

Using the second list employeeSortOrder , is there a way to sort the first list employeeDetails and return the output as based on employeeSortOrder.Id :

> 500  Mark  Pearl Blvd.
>      200  John  Harmington Road.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clean up this question. It is very difficult to discern what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So you want `employeeDetails` to be sorted in the order given by `employeeSortOrder`.

The easiest way to do this would be to create a `Dictionary<EmpId, int>` from the `employeeSortOrder` array. Then create a custom sort method that looks things up in that dictionary.

```
// build the dictionary
Dictionary<EmpId, int> sortDict = new Dictionary<EmpId, int>();
foreach (var x in employeeSortOrder)
{
    sortDict.Add(x.Id, x.Rank);
}

// Now sort, using the dictionary
employeeDetails.Sort((e1, e2) =>
    {
        return sortDict[e1.Id].CompareTo(sortDict[e2.Id]);
    });
```

The way that works is that for each comparison the sort makes, it calls the Lambda function. The Lambda function looks up the employee id in the dictionary and gets its ranking in return.

Comment: Thanks. What values does e1 and e2 contain?

Comment: @Sharpeye: `e1` and `e2` will be of type `ClassEmpInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    employeeDetails.Sort((c1, c2) => employeeSortOrder.FindIndex(e=>e.ranking==c1.empID).CompareTo(employeeSortOrder.FindIndex(e=>e.ranking==c2.empID)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (using LINQ):

```
employeeDetails.OrderBy(e => employeeSortOrder.First(s => s.Id == e.EmpId).Ranking);
```

This assumes that there is always an `EmpID.Id` in `employeeSortOrder` for each `ClassEmpInfo.EmpId` in `employeeDetails`.

Be sure to import the System.Linq namespace.

MSDN for `OrderBy`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx

MSDN for `First`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx